# Show an animated spinner while a backgound task is processing in rails 3, resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for background tasks.
How can i show an animated spinner while a backgound task is processing?
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184061/how-to-show-an-animated-spinner-while-a-background-task-is-processing-in-nested), but it didn't help me

Comment: Take a look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780191/how-to-alert-user-when-a-resque-job-finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've done this before, I've always set a flag on the object itself in the database once it enters Resque, then as soon as the job is done in the Resque task, updated that flag again.  You can use AJAX to monitor the status of that flag and manipulate the page / spinner accordingly.